# How to use Vite HMR API with Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js, vite, hot-module-replacement

I'm trying to use the [Vite HMR API](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-hmr.html) to create a [Pixi.js](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs#readme) app that hot reloads without resetting its state. The high-level idea:

- `main.js` initializes Pixi.js so an imported function `update()` is run every tick.
- The imported `update()` is passed an object with the state so changes can be made in `main.js` context.

**I got `update.js` to hot update, but the app doesn't reflect the modified function:**

```js
// update.js
if (import.meta.hot) {
    import.meta.hot.accept()
}
export default function update(delta, state) {
    state.bunny.rotation += 0.1 * delta;
}
```

**I think it's because Pixi is still using the old `update()`:**

```
// main.js
app.ticker.add((delta) => { update(delta, state) });
```

**So I tried to [accept updates in `main.js` when `update.js` was updated](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-hmr.html#hot-accept-deps-cb):**

```js
// main.js
import update from './update.js';

if (import.meta.hot) {
    import.meta.hot.accept('./update.js', (newUpdate) => {
    console.log('Update ticker here.');
  })
}
```

However this callback is not called when `update.js` is hot updated. Why is the callback not getting called?

---

I have tried some other things, like porting this [Snowpack HMR example](https://ar.al/2020/12/31/snowpack-hmr-from-scratch/) to Vite. I had problems/errors setting the module state (`module.setState(import.meta.hot.data)`), but I don't think I need to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think it's because Pixi is still using the old update():

Your assumption is correct. Vite's job ends when the new module is imported and you get notified through the `accept` callback. You need to make sure that you don't keep internal references to the original module, since Vite is not able to intercept and replace those references.

```
import { update } from './update';

// create your PIXI app

let updateFunction = update;
    
app.ticker.add((delta) => {
  updateFunction(delta, state);
});

if (import.meta.hot) {
   import.meta.hot.accept('./update', (newModule) => {
     updateFunction = newModule.update;
   });
}
```